# Flooding Socket.IO Node server

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, raspberry-pi

I am doing an interactive game with a Raspberry Pi and Sockets and I emit with a high rate (1-20 per second per listener) from the RPI to the server that's on the laptop. 
At some times everything is ok but other times it gets really buggy (taking a few ms to display changes).

Is there a way to optimize this communication with Socket.IO or are there any alternative ways on doing this?

P.S. I'm doing plain emits with no data to be lighter.
EDIT:

Server:

```
socket.on('player1', function(){
    //doing calculations
});
socket.on('player2', function(){
    //doing calculations
});
socket.on('player3', function(){
    //doing calculations
});
```

Client:

```
socket.emit('player1');
socket.emit('player2');
socket.emit('player3');
```

**EDIT 2**
These are the "calculations" that I am doing when I receive an emit from the Pi, it's some very basic RaphaelJS object animations.

```
var pos = this.objects[index].getPointAtLength(this.counter[index]);
this.e[index].attr({
    x: pos.x, 
    y: pos.y
});
this.counter[index]++;
```

Comment: What's your code? We can't understand what you are really doing without it

Comment: First off, "really buggy" is not a meaningful description of what type of problem you actually have.  Second off, you can somewhat obviously coalesce your messages to send fewer messages with more data in each, but without understanding what you're really doing here, we can't really advise very specifically.

Comment: @jfriend00 it's not possible to send fewer messages because it's a realtime game and when the players interact they need to see immediately on the screen the interaction

Comment: @StefanosChrs - then not much we can do without you describing what the actual problem is as "buggy" is not a useful description and also showing us all relevant code.  We don't even, at this point, know what the main problem is - whether your server can't keep up with message traffic or whether you have a concurrency issue or something else?

Comment: @jfriend00 as I mentioned in my description Buggy as all of us know it is when there is a small delay interrupting the normal flow of events. I showed you all the code that has to do with the sockets and that's pretty much it for the communication side. Nothing fancy here, just a simple event emiting from the RPI to the Server

Comment: What are the calculations that are being done?

Comment: Moving some objects on a Canvas using RaphaelJS

Comment: @StefanosChrs could you please include at least a basic example of what your calculations are?

Comment: @Blubberguy22 yes of course, I'm editing the post

Comment: @StefanosChrs Are you just emitting the positions and statistics of the players?

Comment: Nope, just an empty emit for each player

Comment: @StefanosChrs Why? What are the emits there for then? (I'm asking these questions because you wanted optimization, and it helps me answer if I know these things. For optimization, one would usually not have three data sends that lack information)

Comment: I need to do some animations based on the user interactions with some sensors I have on the Pi. The flow is very specific so I don't need to send data with the emit because I know what happens next, also I can't join the emits because each player has async interaction with the Pi